# call the procedure but the results are null on the username

Tags: yii2

in the history table username always null , what's wrong with the code

```
<?= Html::submitButton('Masuk', ['class' => 'btn btn-lg btn-info btn-shadow btn-block', 'name' => 'login-button']); 

            $username = isset($_POST["username"]);
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $device = Funct::detectDevice();

            $list = Funct::Loghistory($username,$ip,$device);
            ?>
```

Comment: what is type of username field in database? also show Loghistory code and are you confirm there is username in $_POST?

Comment: Show your  controller/action code  ..